# LINQ Query - calculating percentage from sum fields in the same statement

Tags: linq

From the below query I am struggling to get the Failure Percentage as it is always coming as zero. Am I doing something wrong.

```
from n in calculateOrderStatus
group n by new { n.OrderDate.Date, n.OrderDate.Hour } into h
select new 
{
    Failed = h.Sum(n => n.Failed), 
    Success = h.Sum(n => n.Success),
    FailurePercentage = (h.Sum(n => n.Failed) /  h.Sum(n => n.Success))  * 100
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing integer division, not floating point: therefore dividing Failed by Success will always give you zero if Failed < Success. Multiply Failed by 100 first, *then* divide by Success.

i.e. `FailurePercentage = 100 * h.Sum(n => n.Failed) /  h.Sum(n => n.Success)`

Comment: Then either `h.Sum(n => n.Failed)` is zero, or very small compared to `h.Sum(n => n.Success)`. But there's nothing wrong with the code otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

try casting the operands of your calculation to a floating point type:

```
 FailurePercentage = ((double)h.Sum(n => n.Failed) /  (double)h.Sum(n => n.Success))  * 100.0
```

(though technically casting the first one is enough)